# Can't solve - C# SQL checking two tables and updating one

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-update, sqldatasource

I'm trying to update a Modules table, when the user selects a course they're brought to a modules page, then they search for lecturer and select him/her.

So I know it updates my table, (because I tried without the roleID bit in it in the back end code), but it updates all records where CourseID and ModuleID are the same including student records. I want it to update only Lecturer

Trying to add in a last piece of code, that checks if the searched for user's role is equal to 2 (a lecturer in my Users role table).

I have a modules table and a user role table.

Here is the front end code

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT Lecturer_Records.UserID, Lecturer_Records.FirstName, Lecturer_Records.Surname, Lecturer_Records.PhoneNumber, Users.Email, User_Role.RoleID 
            FROM Lecturer_Records 
            INNER JOIN Users ON Lecturer_Records.UserID = Users.UserID 
            INNER JOIN User_Role ON Users.UserID = User_Role.UserID 
            WHERE (Users.Email = @email)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="email" QueryStringField="searchlects" />
                <asp:SessionParameter Name="ModuleID" SessionField="ModuleID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:SessionParameter Name="CourseID" SessionField="CourseID" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>




        <asp:GridView ID="SearchResult" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SearchResult_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="UserID" SortExpression="UserID" ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Surname" HeaderText="Surname" SortExpression="Surname" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PhoneNumber" HeaderText="PhoneNumber" SortExpression="PhoneNumber" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RoleID" HeaderText="RoleID" SortExpression="RoleID" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And here is the back end code

```
protected void SearchResult_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

         // open new connection
            SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
            connection1.Open();

            string SearchUser = SearchResult.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
            string RoleID = SearchResult.SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text;
            string Module = (string)Session["ModuleID"];
            string Course = (string)Session["CourseID"];

            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [Modules] SET UserID = '" + SearchUser + "' WHERE ModuleID = '" + Module + "' AND CourseID = '" + Course + "' RoleID = '" + 2 + "'", connection1);
            // and where users roleid = 2 in users role table
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>");
            Response.Write("alert('Lecturer Updated');");
            Response.Write("document.location.href='APMDefault.aspx';");
            Response.Write("</script>");
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure your update query _really_ updates? Because it need `AND/OR` before `RoleID` column in `WHERE` part. And based on their names, they are numeric typed columns and that's why you should delete single quotes for them. Also you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. As a last thing, use `using` statement to dispose your connection and command automatically.

Comment: it does when i take out the RoleID = '" + 2 + "'" bit but updates all records